# MySQL Spatial - Convert from SRID 31287 to 4326

Tags: mysql, spatial, srid

In MySQL I have a a database with around 100 tables.

They all contain a column called ´shape´, this is a polygon type field.

It contains information in what I believe (st_srid returns 1, but it's wrong) is SRID 31287.

I would like to convert it to SRID 4326, how would I go about to do this?

**UPDATE**
This is a very old question with very old answers, recently a new answer was submitted which is IMHO the approach to use if the versioning is correct. I am not marking the new answer as correct as it's unfair to the person who gave the correct answer at the time of the question. If you're on version 8 however, follow this answer to this question by UncertaintyP : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65314337/2973474

Comment: Please see my answer as the chosen answer is simple wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559573/124486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1. Your internal representation is wrong, it's SRID 1, and it should be SRID 31287. Changing an internal representation is possible in every database: [MySQL will get a mutator for it in version 8, `ST_SRID`](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8543), PostGIS has [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)
2. You need to actually convert from SRID 31287 to SRID 4326. This is possible **ONLY** in PostGIS. Neither [MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_transform-missing/) nor [Microsoft SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2723/6052) can reproject an SRID.

To tackle the first problem in PostGIS, you'd use [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html), and to tackle the second problem you'd use [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Comment: That's correct - I switched to postgis during development. Dont know why that answer was marked as correct.

Answer (score 3):

An update of the conversion in MySQL for the lost souls that found their way to this question:

In version 8 you now have [ST_Transform](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-transform)

```
mysql> SET @p = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(52.381389 13.064444)', 4326);
mysql> SELECT ST_AsText(@p);
+----------------------------+
| ST_AsText(@p)              |
+----------------------------+
| POINT(52.381389 13.064444) |
+----------------------------+
mysql> SET @p = ST_Transform(@p, 4230);
mysql> SELECT ST_AsText(@p);
+---------------------------------------------+
| ST_AsText(@p)                               |
+---------------------------------------------+
| POINT(52.38208611407426 13.065520672345304) |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Will update my question to highlight this answer. Thanks for answering such an old question.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL it looks like this:

```
UPDATE `table name` SET `column name` = ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(`column name`), 4326);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

(For MySQL)

```
UPDATE Table SET SpatialColumn = ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(SpatialColumn), 4326);
```

Comment: This changes the SRID value, but does not transform the data itself, which will make it invalid.

Answer (score -2):

I can only hope this will help you (either directly or as a pointer) as its an answer for SQL Server, but how about...

```
UPDATE Table SET SpatialColumn = Geometry::STGeomFromText(SpatialColumn.STAsText(), 4326);
```

Naturally, you can swap Geometry for Geography if you're using Geography columns.  You'll need to replace Table with your table name and SpatialColumn with the name of your Spatial Column.

NOTE: This assumes your SRID of 31287 defines coordinates as decimal latitude / longitude values.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Of course setting the SRID doesn't transform the coordinates. I misread the question when I answered it, simply seeing it as wanting to correct/convert the SRID value. But as for "What does this have to do with MySQL?" - absolutely nothing, but as no-one else offered any help, I hoped that a SQL answer (which is what I know) would help set the OP in the right direction and even stated this in the answer. Thankfully however for future viewers, you've provided a better and correct answer.